# CentOS 6.5, mod_wsgi, Apache Cannot load mod_wsgi.so into server, undefined symbol: PyExc_StopIteration

Tags: apache2, mod-wsgi, python-3.3, centos6

**The problem:**

I can't start apache server with mod_wsgi. **apachectl -t** says:

httpd: Syntax error on line 202 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /etc/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so: undefined symbol: **PyExc_StopIteration**

**Here's what I got so far:**

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)  
Python 3.3.5
mod_wsgi-3.4 (latest)
```

---

### **python compilation:**

```
wget http://python.org/ftp/python/3.3.5/Python-3.3.5.tar.xz
tar xf Python-3.3.5.tar.xz
cd Python-3.3.5
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-shared --with-threads
make && make altinstall
```

---

### **mod_wsgi compilation:**

./configure --with-python=/usr/local/bin/python3.3

```
checking for apxs2... no
checking for apxs... /usr/sbin/apxs
checking Apache version... 2.2.15
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
```

then I edit Makefile - replace:

```
LDLIBS =  -lpython3.3 -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm
```

with

```
LDLIBS =  -python3.3 -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm
```

(sorry, I can't remember where I've read this, but it helps me last time I sucessfully install mod_wsgi on same system configuration)

make

*---plenty of warnings---*

make install

### SOLUTION:

---

since I can't answer my own question "till 8 reputation", I gonna edit my own post.

---

Being familiar with compilation process not too much, I've started looking into parameters... and there were no folder "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/config"! With a wild guess, I made next changes to generated Makefile, and now it works!

`< LDFLAGS =  -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib/python3.3/config`

`< LDLIBS =  -lpython3.3 -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm`

## ------------

`> LDFLAGS =  -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib/python3.3/config-3.3m`

`> LDLIBS =  -lpython3.3m -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm`

Comment: Changing it to '-python3.3' is plain wrong. Don't do it. Put it back and try again. Make sure you run 'make distclean' in the directory and rerun configure before running make again.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton, then it fails:
(read [newline] as \n, I can't format code well in comment)

*---plenty of warnings---*

    
[newline]/usr/lib64/apr-1/build/libtool --silent --mode=link gcc -o mod_wsgi.la  -rpath /usr/lib64/httpd/modules -module -avoid -version    mod_wsgi.lo -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib/python3.3/config -lpython3.3 -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm
[newline]/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython3.3
[newline]collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
[newline]apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536
[newline].
[newline]make: *** [mod_wsgi.la] Error 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being familiar with compilation process not too much, I've started looking into parameters... and there were no folder "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/config"! With a wild guess, I made next changes to generated Makefile, and now it works!

`< LDFLAGS =  -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib/python3.3/config`

`< LDLIBS =  -lpython3.3 -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm`

## ------------

`> LDFLAGS =  -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib/python3.3/config-3.3m`

`> LDLIBS =  -lpython3.3m -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm`

Comment: Yes, you would need to do that with last official release of mod_wsgi when the installation of Python incorporates the ABIFLAG into the directory and library version. It is fixed already for future version of mod_wsgi, whenever that may be released.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton What future version do you refer to?

Comment: Have you even tried the latest version? It was fixed over a year ago.